# Pass multiple parameters from a jQuery function to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jQuery that passes variables onto a PHP form:

```
function getSecondaryCat(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "category-get-secondary.php",
        data:'primary_cat='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
            $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
        }
    });
}
```

The above passes the data onto to a PHP function

```
//Get primary category value
$postPrimaryCat = $_POST['primary_cat'];
```

Now I want to pass another variable called `category_type` how do I add it in my jQuery above?

Comment: `data: { primary_cat: val, category_type: val2 } `

Comment: Does nobody [EVER Read The Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: use this `data:'primary_cat='+val+'&category_type='+type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way.

Using array into data parameters.

```
data: {primary_cat:val,category_type:cat_var}
```

Complete example,

```
function getSecondaryCat(val, cat_var) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "category-get-secondary.php",
    data: {primary_cat:val,category_type:cat_var},
    success: function(data){
        $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
        $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
    }
});
}
```

Comment: But pretty much covered by @Daan in his comment

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try like this:

data parameter used to pass the values, so you can append values here as in the url

```
function getSecondaryCat(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "category-get-secondary.php",
            data:'primary_cat='+val+'&category_type='+cat_val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#secondary_cat").html(data);
                $("#tertiary_cat").html('<option value="">Select specific category</option>')
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: I have no experience with jQuery and I was stuck. That is my I asked the question in the first place.